# What is the maximum number of variables and constraints in NLOPT used on Python?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nlopt

I guess each NLOPT algorithm has different scales. I'm more interested about the Global Optimizer ISRES and Local Optimizer COBYLA. What are their max limits? Thanks!

Comment: Often this is not a very useful question. Even though the solver may accept MAXINT variables, usually you will hit other limits such as running out of memory or patience. Also the model size is not very indicative for the difficulty in solving the model (some small models are very difficult to solve and some large models are easy).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But generally, can a model size of a thousand variables be handled even if it takes a long time? Also I'd love to know a little more about running out of memory. Is non-linear programming very memory intensive?

Comment: Yes, for large, sparse NLP problems we use specialized sparse solvers instead of simpler dense solvers. Of course eventually these also run out of memory.